# Array Understanding :

Tags: c, arrays

```
int m,digit[100],i=0, n = 15;
while(n)
{
    m = n%2;
    digit[i] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[m];
    n = n/2;
}
```

I did not understand what is digit[i] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[m];

Comment: Note that `n%2` is either 0 or 1. Also, `i` starts at 0 ... and stays there. So basically, that line reduces to either `digit[0] = '0'` or `digit[0] = '1'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just needs basic understanding about arrays and strings in C.

**Arrays basically use two aspects to work:**

1. Starting address of the array
2. Offset to add to above address.

In memory, arrays are interpreted as:

```
  arr[index] => arr(starting address) and index(offset)
```

During execution, the `offset` is added to `starting address` to retrive the vale.

**String also has a basic rule:**

String in quotes : "Stackoverflow" returns the starting address of itself. So when you are using:

```
 "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[m]
```

The part in quotes returns the `starting address` of  "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" and `m` is the `index(offset)`.

Hope this helps. Though, these are very basic concepts, start with some tutorials to know about these, may be :
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/

Answer (score 2):

`digit[i] ="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[m];` is the `m`th letter of `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`.